Do generalized uncertainty principles violate the triviality of second Hochschild cohomology group of Heisenberg algebra?
The second Hochschild cohomology group of Heisenberg algebra is trivial and it means that we can not deform $[x,p]=i$ further, but there are tons of papers on generalized uncertainty principles which deform UP in different ways. Do these deformations trivial (so what is the aim of it?) or I am missing something.

The second Hochschild cohomology of the universal enveloping algebra of the Heisenberg algebra is trivial. Deformed enveloping algebras are quantum groups, which are a certain type of Hopf algebra. These Do not provide non-trivial deformations of quantum mechanics. They are important however in other areas for example knot theory and integrable systems as well as topological QFT.

Regarding your title question, I would say it is the other way around, because the GUP arises quite naturally in higher order effective actions. So it is the second Hochschild cohomology group of the Heisenberg algebra that is not well suited for this topic.

@Simp, all GUP deformations are not q-deformations.

Do you mean that there are deformations of UP which are not q-deformations. Then yes. If you mean that no UP-deformation is a q-deformation than then your claim is false. Could you clarify?

clearly there are some q-deformed UP, its OK to me. but there are many non q-deformed UP in literature which are puzzling to me from Hochschild second cohomology group. I believe that all of them are trivial. Suppose that $[x,p]=i(1+\alpha p^2)$, which is a GUP in papers (for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.00609  equation 8). I can define $x'=x$ and $p=f(p')$, and impose canonical commutation $[x',p']=i$, with the following equation $\frac{df(p')}{dp'}=1+\alpha f^2(p')$, which can be easily integrated.  So GUP is just the same as usual UP.

Hm I remember that there is a theorem that states that $HH^2(A_1)$ is vanishing when $char(\mathbb F)=0$. So there are possiblities that deformations excist.

This should help. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/seminars/download.php%3Ffid%3D112&ved=2ahUKEwjEr8-D29GIAxXIgf0HHcaWLUkQFnoECCAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2EsFz-R4PT-NRLvFepk-iU

@Simp, Thank you so much Simp.
